# CakePHP - change Model variable on Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Node Model with variable translateFields (using CakePhp):

```
class Node extends AppModel {
   public $translateFields = array('title');
   .....
}
```

For any case (not all), I want change to:

```
public $translateFields = array('title','field_image');
```

How I do this? Change in Controller or where?

Comment: Where do you call Node class?

Comment: I would either do it in the relevant actions directly, or derive a new class with the extra value if some of the methods have to be modified as well, and then instantiate the right one in said actions. This is just a first idea though; without more details on the situation it is difficult to tell.

Answer (score 1):

See all Models inherit AppModel ,correct? So define the variable in AppModel. Therefore it will be accessed as will be defined in parent. Also you can override like you used different array indexes.Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In a Controller or another Model which uses the Node model:

`$this->Node->translateFields = array('title','field_image');`

In a method of Node:

`$this->translateFields = array('title','field_image');`